# No active image when baking texture

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I'm new to blender, so it could be something very simple, but I've been trying to get this texture to bake for two days now. I've watched a bunch of different tutorials and I keep running into different issues.
https://gyazo.com/eb7e89db3ce13c0805ecb87b07e5343c

https://gyazo.com/9a74ca5c29ffc35b9e6d6c5eb107389a

I unwrapped the well, added an image node in every material, selected the well texture in every section and changed the engine to Cycles to bake. It gets four done, then fails with the error message "no active image found, add a material or bake to an external image file"

Comment: I would suggest to attach  simplified blend file that still produce the error via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)